# Time period in Objective-C

Tags: java, objective-c, jodatime, period

Doing a small project I have received some Java code that I should rewrite into Objective-C(for iPhone to be precise). I came across this piece of code:

```
public class Period {
  private org.joda.time.Period jodaPeriod;
  public Period(org.joda.time.Period jodaPeriod) {
    Validate.isTrue(PeriodType.standard().equals(jodaPeriod.getPeriodType()),
            "The jodaPeriod argument must be a standard type period");
    this.jodaPeriod = jodaPeriod;
  }

  public Period(int months) {
    this(new org.joda.time.Period(months / 12, months % 12, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0));
  }

  public Period(int years, int months) {
    this(new org.joda.time.Period(years, months, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0));
  }
  //some other code
}
```

After a quick research I got the basics of the `JodaTime period`, but I still don't know how to do that in `Objective-C`. I've read about `CMTime`, but it's not really what I was looking for.

Thank you, any help would be greatly appreciated. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not entirely sure what you're trying to use this for, but you'll want to look at:

1. [NSCalendar](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSCalendar_Class/Reference/NSCalendar.html)
2. [NSDateComponents](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSDateComponents_Class/Reference/Reference.html)
3. [NSDate](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSDate_Class/Reference/Reference.html)

If you give more information about what you're actually trying to achieve, we can explain how you'd use these.

Comment: hi, thanks for your answer. It is sort of a long-term planner. Like "I want to achieve that and that in `y` years and `m` months". So that's why I need these years and months. And it looks like `NSDateComponents` is what I was looking for. Going to check it tomorrow(or today if I will have time after fixing one bug).